# Django rest framework custom renderer in testing response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-tests

I'm trying to make my testing code in my django app. My app has a custom renderer class so the response will look like this:

```
{
    "code": 422,
    "message": "Unprocessable Entity",
    "data": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
        ]
    }
}
```

My test code:

```py
class AuthenticationTestCase(TestCase):
    """Test login and registration"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_login_success(self):
        """Test success login"""

        payload = {
            'email': 'test@test.com',
            'password': 'password',
            'is_active': True
        }

        create_user(**payload)

        res = self.client.post(LOGIN_URL, payload)

        self.assertEqual(res.data['code'], status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The client response only return:

```
"non_field_errors": [
    "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
]
```

Question is, can I make my testing client response using my custom renderer class as well?

EDIT:

This is my custom renderer class:

```
class CustomRenderer(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        status_code = renderer_context['response'].status_code
        response = {
            'code': status_code,
            'message': renderer_context['response'].status_text,
            'data': data,
        }

        renderer_context['response'].status_code = 200

        return super(CustomRenderer, self) \
            .render(response, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I need to set response's data in renderer class to my custom response like this:

```
renderer_context['response'].data = response
```